# Raspberry Pi Camera(8 MP) shows blur images in Android Things installed on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, camera, android-things, pi-3b+

Raspberry Pi Camera(8 MP) shows blur images in Android Things installed on Raspberry Pi.

I use the code from Google Sample -- Doorbell application and capture the image but Image is too blur (Camera is 8 MP).

How to focus, autoFocus or how to set focus to Camera? 
Can I handle focus on this camera via Android Things Coding(Programmatically) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pi Camera V2/V2.1 is a fixed-focus lens, it doesn't support auto focus or programmability.

The only way to tweak the focus is via manual adjust of the image distance v, according to the formula 1/v + 1/u = 1/f, then change the object distance u.

[image]

For detailed steps, you can check the posts:

- [Adjust Raspberry Pi camera lens to fix the blurry issue](https://zpjiang.me/2020/05/28/picamera-adjust-focus/)
- [Fixing the blurry focus on some Raspberry Pi Camera v2 models](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/fixing-blurry-focus-on-some-raspberry-pi-camera-v2-models)

Answer (score 4):

The Raspberry Pi camera is manual focus only. It's pretty tolerant of focusing errors, though, so if you set the focus to a good compromise distance, it will probably be sharp enough.

My Raspberry Pi Camera came with a small round plastic tool with a hole in the center that looks like this: [image: focusing tool for Raspberry Pi Camera]

It fits onto the camera lens, and you can adjust the focus by rotating it while pressing down to keep it locked onto the board.
[image: focusing tool on camera]

If you lost your focusing tool (or never got one, different suppliers might not provide them), you could carefully use pliers to rotate the lens assembly (the round part with four flanges, not the square part) until it is focused, or buy a focusing tool (Adafruit sells them as "Lens Adjustment Tool for Raspberry Pi Camera").[image: Which part of the camera to rotate in order to focus it]

Comment: Thanks. I will use this tool for focusing camera. But there is any code for focusing camera programmatically?